# Custom Autocomplete Adapter Android

Tags: java, android

I wish to have a auto-complete text-box which comes up with the users contact names. My code is as follows.

```
private void getContactNames()
{
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
   _contactAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String tmp = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
        _contactAdapter.add(tmp);

    }
}
```

Setting the adapter:

```
    AutoCompleteTextView contactName = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.contactName);
    contactName.setAdapter(_contactAdapter);
```

When I do this, the adapter has all the contact names in there (238 contacts). However, when I start typing into the text box, the auto complete does not show.

Funny, as when I test it out doing this:

```
String[] ab = new String[] {"aaaaa", "bbbbb"};
       _contactAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,ab);
```

it will show "aaaaa" and "bbbbb" when typing in to the text box.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Tom

****EDIT***

Just thought I would follow up. It does seem to be the sheer amount of contacts that is preventing it from appearing. Any way to get around this?

Comment: its work when you have already list of user before set it in auto complete. thats why its not show you. if you want to search directly from phone database then use. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (cursor.moveToNext())
{
    int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
    String tmp = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
    //_contactAdapter.add(tmp);

    //  get all names in a new arraylist and then assign it to 
      arrayList.add(tmp);
}
```

and then assign it to your adapter as

```
 _contactAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrayList);
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your reply but alas it did not work. The strings are in the "mObjects" member in the adapter, yet do not appear when I start typing into the box. Is it because the strings are too long? or I have too many elements (238). Cheers

Comment: try setting up the threshold then contactName.setThreshold(1);
and String is class type so it do not worry abt the limitation your strings would easily fit into that